# How to derive a new object property from 2 existing object properties directly in workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is there a way to compute a new object property derived from existing properties of that object, directly in workshop ? E.g. a date_diff new object property out of 2 date type properties of that object.

Didn't found any way to do that directly in Workshop

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there are a few existing options:

- Using a function-backed derived column with the Object Table / Object List / Property List widget to display a dynamically derived column local to those widgets
- Embedding Quiver Dashboard widget within your Workshop module and using Quiver's front-end data transformation options (e.g., the Transform Table)
- Modifying your upstream data pipeline to materialize the additional column as a first-class property type on your object type

Longer term, Workshop is working on a new feature set called "Derived Properties" that aims at enabling more flexible front-end transformation options (e.g., appending a 1:1 link object property or 1:M linked object aggregation as a new derived property onto a given object type or doing intra-object type column math as in your example). This feature set is in early testing now but does not yet have a confirmed generally available release date.

Paul